# Pop up credential box for webview

Tags: android, webview

first of all i am new to java programing so my question will be a little tricky
I have a sharepoint website that can be open from my mobile or desktop but it popup a windows to enter my username and password

When i try to use this website using webview the popup windows do not show

Even when i used setHttpAuthUsernamePassword it doesn’t work

Always give me an error ‘401 unauthorized’

If anyone can give me a full example it will be great

Thanks ..

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Can you give us more details regarding the exact client api you are trying to use?

Comment: Hello thanks for your fast reply , i am using API 15: Android 4.0.3 (IceCreamSandwitch)

Comment: Any updates regarding to my question?